# QML multiple window with keeping the state of all windows

Tags: qt, qml, stackview

I want to develop a qml application that starts with the main window and three buttons are available in the main window. By pressing each button a new page(Layout) should show up, but after returning to the main window, the state of the previous page should not change. I have tried ListView but it did not work, because it destroys the Item after pop(). Here is my Code(PagesOne.qml is a sample for three pages that I want to open):

> main.qml

```js
    ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 8 * Screen.width / 10
    height: 8 * Screen.height / 10
    color: "#154c79"
    // Keep the window on the given x,y on starting
    Component.onCompleted: {
        x: Screen.width / 10
        y: Screen.height / 10
    }

    minimumWidth: 700
    minimumHeight: 400


    // Current Working Layout
    Component {
        id: pageOne
        PageOne{}
    }

    // Empty Layout
    Component {
        id: pageTwo
        PageTwo{}
    }

    // Empty Layout
    Component {
        id: pageThree
        PageThree{}
    }

    property variant items: [pageOne.createObject(), pageTwo.createObject(), pageThree.createObject()]

    StackView {
        id: stack
        anchors.fill: parent
        // initialItem: pageOne
        Component.onCompleted: {
            stack.push(items[2], {"destroyOnPop": false})
            stack.push(items[1], {"destroyOnPop": false})
            stack.push(items[0], {"destroyOnPop": false})
        }
    }

    // change layout on call
    function load_layout(layout){

        console.log("#############",  stack.depth, "#############")

        switch (layout){
            case 'one':
                stack.pop(0, {"destroyOnPop": false})
                break;
            case 'two':
                stack.pop(1, {"destroyOnPop": false})
                break;
            case 'three':
                stack.pop(2, {"destroyOnPop": false})
                break;
            default:
                stack.pop(0, {"destroyOnPop": false})
        }
    }
}
```

> PageOne.qml:

```js
    Item{
    id: root
    // anchors.fill: parent
    // Empty rect
    Rectangle{
        color: "#03fc88"
        anchors.fill: parent

        TextField {
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            width: 120
            height: 60
            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter: ")
        }

        Label{
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text:  "Page two"
        }

        // return button
        RoundButton {
            id: btnBack
            text: "\u003C"
            onClicked: {
                if(text === "\u003C"){
                    load_layout('one')
                    }
                }
            }

    }

}
```

Is there any suggestion that helps me?

Comment: According to your code you mean `page` or `frame`, not `window`. what does `the state of the previous window should not change` mean? please clarify the question. Also check [this note](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#push-method) from the doc: _Only items that StackView created itself (from a Component or url) will be destroyed when popped_

Comment: @folibis By state of window (page) I mean if there is a textfield in the `pageTwo` and user type something, after going back to main window and selecting `pageTwo` again the textField keeps the data.

Comment: I guess if you will push an item, not component it will keep the state i.e. will not be destroyed by QtQuick.

Comment: Another option is using `replace()` instead of `push()`

Comment: @folibis Because of **Only items that StackView created itself (from a Component or URL) will be destroyed when popped**  I have `createObject()` from my component and then push it to StackView. I tried also to use Item instead of Component (I just replace it) and still StackView destroy it. I am not sure now if StackView is the correct choice in my case for handling multiple pages.`replace()` is the same it will destroy the previous state of the window. As I said I want all the information in windows to stay as the user change between pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example:

```js
    import QtQuick 2.15
    import QtQuick.Window 2.15
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
    
    Window {
        height: 800
        width: 600
        visible: true
        title: qsTr("Stack test")
    
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 0
            StackView {
                id: stack
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                initialItem: screen1
                Rectangle {
                    id: screen1
                    color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1)
                }
                Rectangle {
                    id: screen2
                    color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1)
                }
                Rectangle {
                    id: screen3
                    color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1)
                }
            }
            RowLayout {
                id: bar
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                spacing: 0
                Button {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 300
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                    text: "Change color"
                    onClicked: {
                        stack.currentItem.color = Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);
                    }
                }
    
                Button {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 300
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                    text: "Next"
                    onClicked: {
                        switch(stack.currentItem)
                        {
                        case screen1:
                            stack.replace(screen2)
                            break;
                        case screen2:
                            stack.replace(screen3)
                            break;
                        case screen3:
                            stack.replace(screen1)
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code works for me and it keeps the page's state. I will try to load my **PageOne.qml* file in code to see how it works in that manner. Thank you.

Comment: It works perfectly when I load (read) another .qml file and the state of the pages did not change. Just I had some anchors problem which was not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Because, in your main page, you use `Component`, by definition, QML can create and destroy as many instances of the page corresponding to push/pull on the stack. So, the feature you described is as per design.

If you want to maintain an instance that is persistent, do not use `Component`. Instead, declare an instance of the pages but keep them invisible.

In the following example, I declare Pages each with a different TextField. As you switch between the pages, you can resume editing the TextField on that page exactly where you left it.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: "MenuPage.qml"
    }

    PageOne {
        id: pageOne
        visible: false
    }
    PageTwo {
        id: pageTwo
        visible: false
    }
    PageThree {
        id: pageThree
        visible: false
    }
}

// MenuPage.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    header: Label { text: "MainPage" }
    ColumnLayout {
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Page One")
            onClicked: stackView.push(pageOne)
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Page Two")
            onClicked: stackView.push(pageTwo)
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Page Three")
            onClicked: stackView.push(pageThree)
        }
    }
}

// PageOne.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    header: Label { text: "Page One" }
    ColumnLayout {
        TextField {
            text: "sheep"
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Back")
            onClicked: stackView.pop()
        }
    }
}

// PageTwo.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    header: Label { text: "Page Two" }
    ColumnLayout {
        TextField {
            text: "magic"
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Back")
            onClicked: stackView.pop()
        }
    }
}

// PageThree.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    header: Label { text: "Page Three" }
    ColumnLayout {
        TextField {
            text: "xyzzy"
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Back")
            onClicked: stackView.pop()
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAG7XicxZNPi8IwEMXv/RQhJ/dS7z1aWFhw2ZWVvcd2tINpUpN0tYrffZP+sxYRtaC5lDxm8jK/l2KaSWXIzMxyjNYenm39UAqjJNd9fcoKmRvtfbMVkINH7PoxLFr/ImzrvVsYB0Q3eqsyESVSaX+JnAckYwqEObUINMj4h4E0IPQTRO48/E3KaVlz9MqPE78E9LyySm21P9S44BCQJeMa6v6mfb6VF9qtemN7ouCSf6lfP8LOMB6T7mw9vgNiSIDFoAIyZQvg5EAM7IwDyVC4KlpPEEqep6Lq7wwxyY2RoiO4VR2x0XM1oqWTRUzfzkqkCLm9EHTz9rNcJ6M6klP58U4zG8hdZrZ+gJkL7z4719E3bCKuX+lTEm6TuZ7w3Fa/I/D4IgqqE4CMPsJvYtHcRE5mo2u8bH7P4+Ue1yBeKVth9Fpe7gE+kVj5hwxitiv2++IlzP4BYUH4Fg==)

Comment: yes you are right. I found the problem. I used this approach in my several tries as well, but as my anchors was not correct the pages did not show up.So  I though something is wrong with using StackView, but the problem was anchors as well... .

Comment: StackView should be positioned properly. The pages will inherit the StackView geometry. In my example, I use `anchors.fill: parent` on the StackView.